# how to react to button pushed in ASP.NET Core 2.0 razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm on my first asp.net core v.2 project, and are looking for how to respond to these two user actions:

```
   a) selection in a dropdown box.  
   c) a button click.
```

It should probably be server side, so not in javascript, since they will work through a RESTfull web api and control a microwave own. (the timer and start/stop).

1: ad a) I've populated the dropdown with 3 entries, but cannot get the selected time to be selected in the dropdown. How do I do that?

2: ad a) When the user select a different time, I want to be able to call my microwave and set the newly selected time. - Basically I want to go the the page controller, and set the time from there.

3: ad b) How do I get the C# code, where I can start or stop the microwave based on which button is pushed? - is that in the controller or on the cs file of the page.cshtml page?

thanks for your awnsers...

Answer (score 0):

A submit button click inside a form can send data from browser to server action method without javascript. But a dropdown cannot do it alone on the change event (without an explicit form submission) without javascript.

> 1: I've populated the dropdown with 3 entries, but cannot get the selected time to be selected in the dropdown. How do I do that?`

If you are using the SELECT tag helper with a view model, you should be able to select it.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string SelectedVal { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Items {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new MyViewModel();
  vm.Items = new List<SelectListItem>{
     new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="1" },
     new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="2" },
     new SelectListItem { Value="3" , Text="3"}
  };

  vm.SelectedVal = "2";  // This will pre select the second item in dropdown

  return View(vm);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
  <select asp-for="SelectedVal" asp-items="@Model.Items" >
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in your HttpPost Create action method, you will get the SelectedVal

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
{
   //check model.SelectedVal
   // to do : return something
}
```

> 2: ad a) When the user select a different time, I want to be able to
>   call my microwave and set the newly selected time. - Basically I want
>   to go the the page controller, and set the time from there.

Like i mentioned above, you can click the submit button to submit the newly selected value. But if you do not want to click the submit, then you need to use javascript code to handle the change event on the dropdown and submit the form via javascript.

Comment: ok, it appears that I need to go the javascript way, to handle the updating of the view model, when a different time is selected..
and use that value, when the own is started..